# How to write a bash function to type 'u' then <enter>?

Tags: bash

I keep getting this in my script for unpacking a bunch of tar files
every few files...

```
(Y)es / (N)o / (A)lways / (S)kip all / A(u)to rename all / (Q)uit?
```

I want to type 'u' then enter to deal with this after every extraction....

Comment: It seems to me that it would be better to fix your calls to `tar` so that it doesn't generate these prompts in the first place.

Comment: @HoboSapiens sometimes this doesn't really work and you need to handle scriptly!

Comment: @Ma'moonAl-Akash I didn't know about `yes`, probably because I've never found a need with system utilities. Perhaps you'd like to provide an example.

Comment: @HoboSapiens me neither, i have never really needed such a utility like `yes` but sometimes you do need to handle a situation where you don't really want `tar` to override your files/directories, perhaps `yes no` here is a useful scriptable solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `yes`:

```
yes u | your_command
```

From the yes(1) manual page:

> yes - output a string repeatedly until killed
>
> **Synopsis**
>
> ```
> yes [STRING]...
>
> yes OPTION
> ```
>
> **Description**
>
> Repeatedly output a line with all specified STRING(s), or 'y'.

Comment: Up-vote, Never really knew there is such a nice simple command like this, Thanks for sharing :)